# Do linked files located on FileVault partition make the encrypted file readable?

Tags: macos, permission, encryption, filevault

## Question

Does a link, symlink, or macOS finder aliases to a file/directory located on a **version 1** FileVault partition/container/volume to a partition not under the FileVault coverage allow unencrypted access?

```
 # Example
/Volumes/UnEncryptedVolume/Reference-To-Unlocked-FileVault-File     ->   ~/THE_FILEVAULT_FILE
```

## Constraints

- APFS formatted SSD
- Permissions are not restrictive permissions on Database volume. All Users & Staff grouped Users can access it.
- User is logged in, unlocking the FileVault volume
- Link is either soft or hard, has standard permissions
- Finder created alias has default permissions
- Original file is again, standard permissions even if under `$HOME` (Change those UMASKS newcomers! :))
- Original file is on the FileVault container
- Database is on the same Disk, but a different container.
- Disk is APFS formatted (composed of containers, not volumes or partitions, apfs is friggin' confusing IMO)

## File System Structure

My Internal SSD partition structure (not a OEM SSD for those curious)

```sh
+-- Container disk1 
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk1
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      999995129856 B (1000.0 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   314911416320 B (314.9 GB) (31.5% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       685083713536 B (685.1 GB) (68.5% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       999995129856 B (1000.0 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s1 
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
|   |   Name:                      MacOS - Data (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         138089828352 B (138.1 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s2 
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
|   |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         80568320 B (80.6 MB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s3 
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
|   |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Recovery
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         525770752 B (525.8 MB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s4 
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
|   |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         3222294528 B (3.2 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s5 
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (System)
|   |   Name:                      MacOS (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         11236782080 B (11.2 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s6 
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s6 (No specific role)
|       Name:                      Database (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               /Volumes/Database
|       Capacity Consumed:         161548357632 B (161.5 GB)
|       FileVault:                 No
|
```

Comment: Each of the three mechanisms you reference are fundamentally different. Hard or symbolic links behave differently than aliases and with APFS, copy on write and snapshots all are entwined. None of them change the content on the disk, however - they all are metadata, not data. I’m not sure I can follow enough what your problem to solve is to answer this, though.

Comment: Symlinks are just notes for the OS about where the actual target file can be found. If you can read the target you can also read it via the symlink. If you can‘t read the target you can‘t read it via the symlink either. The things you list under Constraints and File System Structure are totally irrelevant for the question here.

Comment: And you can‘t have hardlinks across volumes, actually

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Symlinks do not somehow "circumvent" FileVault encryption.

Symlinks are always "soft" by the way.

Comment: Perhaps I should elaborate on how macOS also has a OS based security regulation for file access that isn't clear on how it relates to actual file permissions. Full Disk access only covers your booted disk, not other volumes/partitions/containers... which I thought would be understood as this is about macs. I'll change my terms for links vs symlinking.

Comment: I however don't see this as correct. There is no actual reasoning or much of anything that answers why.

Comment: I know about "Full Disk Access" and the like - it is part of a security model not unlike what is found on other operating systems. It doesn't come into play at all for this question, which concerns whether or not symbolic links somehow would allow one to bypass FileVault encryption.

Comment: Can you explain why you do not think my answer is correct? (it is correct, but I just wanted to hear your explanation, as that would allow me to more precisely tell you why it is not so... the main question here is really unclear as to why one would think that symbolic links somehow would 'undo' encryption, if I knew why or where that suspicion comes from, it would be a lot easier to give a better answer)

Comment: The end result of this question is if you just hooked up the drive to another computer if that symlink would expose the data. (I took a mac's filevault disk and read it from a linux machine). You basically keep saying I'm an idiot for asking this question and I should just delete it however zero knowledge of how a macOS system gives that disk special treatment or the OS sets limitations rather than the files sytem (I.E. Full disk access is an OS feature and completely moot if a linux system read it)

Comment: is provided in your answer. You may be correct, but you're not providing me with any evidence. macOS treats disks differently and with rules compared to other linux or windows distros where they strictly rely on file permissions and not system  "rules". (example: SIP in macOS means a user can't alter that block of data on the disk. a linux machine doesn't give a danm about that, it just see the data as it is. No OS rules telling it otherwise).

Comment: You're answer isn't correct because it isn't what I'm asking. Filevault isn't just a file thats encrypted. its a macOS functionality that other machines don't know about if they see the data.

Comment: further reasoning on what I mean about filevault not being just an encrypted block of data: encryption has 1 key. Filevault has more than 1. (Proof: user login credentials and icloud recovery key both can unlock the volume, and so does the first enerated recovery key at setup.) these don't act like a basic encryption. Its more system level restrictions than cryptography

Comment: so.. does the third party machine reading the disk see a symlink (created by a user that had proper permissions) that is pointing to "encrypted" data blocks or raw unencrypted data?

Comment: No, the symlink would not expose your data when hooked up to another computer. I did not anywhere state that you're an idiot, nor did I suggest that your delete your question. I just wanted you to clarify what part of this you're unclear about, so that I can give you the right explanation. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, "Full Disk Access" does not not come into play here at all - it is not relevant for this. Therefore it does not matter that "Full Disk Access" is a restriction only enabled when macOS is running (compared to for example Linux).

Comment: It is correct - and I'm trying to give you the evidence you seek, but you're not giving me much to work with. File Vault 2 encrypts the whole drive. Symlinks are a file system feature that in very rough terms lets you create a "pointer" to another file (on this or another file system). There's nothing in symbolic links at all that would somehow "break encryption". If you can let me know what made you think this was possible, or why you're unsure of this - I can give you the explanation for that. And no, macOS is not different to Linux or Windows in this sense regarding "file permissions" [...]

Comment: and "system rules". It is not so that a Linux machine "doesn't give a damn about it". The same type of mechanism exists on Linux as well - actually it exists in multiple forms. For example you can find similar mechanisms in SELinux, which is part of the standard Linux kernel.

Comment: If you do not detail what you're asking, it is hard to answer other than the written question. File Vault is not a file that is encrypted - it is an encrypted disk. You are mistaken in thinking that it is somehow a protection that is only active when macOS is running. File Vault encryption does not suddenly "disappear" or is "circumventable" simply by running Linux. That's not how it works. You can think of it as something similar (in some ways) to dm-crypt on Linux. The whole block device (the disk) is encrypted. You cannot easily circumvent that without having the correct key.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your argument regarding multiple keys. I think you seem to have the misconception that the encryption is not a standard encryption, but rather something "weird" with multiple keys being used for the same encryption. That is not the case. It is a completely standard, basic encryption with one key. However, that's not all. There's also a lot of key management involved. The single key is stored on disk, but encrypted using other keys, so that you can get to the original key, and thus decrypt disk contents, using your several forms of credentials (depending on setup)

Comment: If you want to compare this to something in the Linux world, you'll want to look at LUKS. This is the common way to enable full disk encryption on Linux. LUKS similarly allows you to use multiple keys as a way to get access to the decrypted disk contents.

Comment: You seem to have the idea that symlinks somehow points to data blocks. That is not how symbolic links works - and I can understand why this misconception would create the confusion you have. A symbolic link means that the actual path you point to is stored on the file system. I.e. if you have a symbolic link pointing from "foo" to "/my/path/bar", this means that "/my/path/bar" is literally stored in the file system where "foo" is. This means that symbolic links can easily cross file systems. A symbolic link can thus be invalidated simply by the linked name not existing at the moment [...]

Comment: for example if a file system is unmounted. The same symbolic link can be valid again a short while later, when the file system is again mounted. Or even just deleting and re-creating the file. So as you see, there's no "pointing to data blocks" in a symbolic link, and as such there's nothing different in symbolic links whether the pointed to object is on an encrypted disk or not. It doesn't matter for the symbolic link. A symbolic link can be seen simply as a shorthand for writing out the pointed to path/filename. It will expose no further information than if you just wrote it out yourself.

Comment: This is why symbolic links cannot in any conceivable scenario circumvent File Vault encryption.

Comment: After I answered, you have edited your question to ask more questions about for example Finder aliases. The same kind of argument applies to Finder aliases - they will not in any way circumcent File Vault encryption.